# is it possible to send log to cloudwatch using only winston-cloudwatch without winston?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cloudwatch, winston

As mentioned in docs [winston-cloudwatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-cloudwatch) is there a way to use only winston-cloudwatch to send logs to aws ?

```
import winston from 'winston';
import WinstonCloudWatch from 'winston-cloudwatch';
winston.add(new WinstonCloudWatch({
  logGroupName: 'testing',
  logStreamName: 'first'
}));

winston.error('1');
```

Comment: You want to use a Winston transport without Winston?

Comment: yes , if it is possible how can I achieve it ?

Comment: You could pick apart the transport source to see how ot works and re-write it, but that seems like an odd thing to do. Maybe just see if there are other cloudwatch libs that aren't tied to Winston?